# Bokeh - Plot different colors in different plots

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to plot different batches of data in different plots. I want that for each batch each line has a different color.

This is what I have tried:

```
color = 7
x = df['Time']

TOOLS = "crosshair, hover, reset, pan, save"

p = [figure(title="Title_1", x_axis_label='Elapsed Time (s)', y_axis_label='Voltage [V]', tools = TOOLS, x_range=(0, 100), y_range=(0, 1000)),
                 figure(title="Title_2", x_axis_label='Elapsed Time (s)', y_axis_label='Voltage [V]', tools = TOOLS, x_range=(0, 100), y_range=(0, 1000))]

for i in range(0,20):
    p[0].line(x, df.iloc[:,i], line_color = Magma256[color][i])
for i in range(20,36):
    p[1].line(x, df.iloc[:,i], line_color = Magma256[color][i])

plts = gridplot([p[0],p[1]], ncols = 1,  plot_width = 1000, plot_height = 1000)
show(plts)
```

When trying this I get the following error:

> IndexError: string index out of range

I think that this means that my

> `"line_color = Magma256[color][i]"`

is getting out of range, but how is it possible if it has a 256 size? What can I try?

Comment: To help debugging, you could try adding the line "print(len(Magma256[color]))" right before the line that the error occurs. Maybe it's size isn't what you think.

Comment: @lucas You are right the len(Magma256[color]) is = 7. But then why is it out of range? If my color = 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I solved it.

Apparently I had to read more and more about it. Here are the explanation and the solution, that I used.

Everything is fine in the code the problem is that `Magma256` is a list.

I am trying to use it as a directory. Meaning that if I wanted to use it correctly I have to place the `Directory[index of the list][index of the color inside the list]` e.g. `Magma[256][1]` if I wanted Magma256.

To plot all the lines in both plots with different colors the code looks like this:

```
color = 256 

for i in range(0,20):
    p[0].line(x, df.iloc[:,i], line_color = Magma[color][i])
for i in range(20,36):
    p[1].line(x, df.iloc[:,i], line_color = Magma[color][i])
```